# Error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy trabajando en un `login` de usuarios y me aparece este error les anexo imagen de la tabla usuario en la base de datos

[image: tabla usuario de la base de datos]

El código de la clase conexión en donde me marca el error

```
<?php
class conexion{
    private $conexion;
    private $server= "localhost";
    private $usuario= "root";
    private $pass= "";
    private $db= "senaconnection";
    private $user;
    private $password;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexion= new mysqli($this->server,$this->usuario,$this->pass,$this->db);
        if ($this->conexion->connect_errno) {
            die("Fallo al tratar de conectar con MySQL: (".$this->conexion->connect_errno.")");
        }
    }
    public function cerrar(){
        $this->conexion->close();
    }
    public function login($email,$pass){
    $this->user= $email;
    $this->password= $pass;

    $query="select id_usuario,nombres,apellidos,correo_sena,contraseña from usuario where correo_sena='".$this->user."' and contraseña='".$this->password."'";
    $consulta=$this->conexion->query($query);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
      session_start();

      $_SESSION['id']= $row['id_usuario'];
      $_SESSION['nom']= $row['nombres'];
      $_SESSION['ape']= $row['apellidos'];

      echo "Has iniciado sesion";

      echo $_SESSION['id'];
      echo $_SESSION['nom'];
      echo $_SESSION['ape'];

    }else{

      echo "usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
    }



    }

}




?>
```

[image: error]

Comment: creo q ese error se debe a que le falta un parametro a la funcion mysqli_fetch_array intenta asi haber si ya se soluciona mysqli_fetch_array($consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: ya lo intente y el problema persiste

Comment: Lo que necesito es consultar en la base de datos e lid,los nombres y apellidos de la tabla usuario donde correo_sena sea igual a lo que se digita por formulario y contraseña sea igual a lo que se digita por formulario. si los datos existen inicia sesion ,sino muestra usuario o contraseña incorrectos